# Clear Intent flags from an activity so that it resumes its original launch behavior

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent, flags

My application has an activity defined as launchMode="singleTop" that serves as the root activity.

```
<activity 
    android:name="com.package.LauncherActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTop" 
    <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

The application creates notifications that, when clicked, "restarts" this root activity using a PendingIntent containing an Intent with the flag Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP.

```
Intent newIntent = new Intent(context, LauncherActivity.class);
newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(
    context, 
    (int)System.currentTimeMillis(), 
    newIntent, 
    PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

The idea is that, wherever the person is currently in the app, when they click on the notification it will clear the activity stack and start "from scratch" at this root activity.

This all works properly and as expected.  I always have just the one task, and it correctly clears the stack when the notification's PendingIntent is executed.

My problem occurs following one of these notification "restarts".  If the activity is then placed in the background and then re-launched using one of the various launchers(Recent Apps, Settings->Apps(see Update below, not exactly), etc.), the Intent used by the notification is used to start the activity **including the Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP**.

**UPDATE:** Actually, my problem only applies to attempting to bring the app to the foreground using the "Recent Apps" launcher.  If I use the Settings->App launcher, it launches the app completely from scratch.  Still it's not "resuming" the app, as it did before I overwrote the default launch intent.  Also note that the app DOES resume as expected if I use the longpress-Home resume.  **What's so different about the "Recent Apps" Launcher that makes it keep re-using that intent?**

So at this point, every time they resume the app via a launcher it "clears top" and starts back at the beginning rather than simply resuming the app as it does before the notification's intent was used.  This happens because it's the same instance of the activity, and that activity continues to launch using the intent with which it was launched.  In this case, that means it has the FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP flag every time.

[This post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/vrLdM5mKeoY) pretty much hit's the nail on the head, but my particular problem is not resolved.  In this post they address how to properly ignore(or use) the Extras in the Bundle of this re-used intent.  But I cannot figure out a way to clear the *flags* on that intent so that it stops launching using the CLEAR_TOP flag.

I only want it to launch using the CLEAR_TOP flag one time, when the notification is pressed.  I want subsequent launches of the app to perform the same way as it did before the notification was pressed, which simply resumed the app/activity stack wherever the user was(rather than starting from scratch every time).

I understand why the activity is re-using the intent.  I just need to find a way to either stop it from doing that, or somehow clear the CLEAR_TOP flag from that intent so that it goes back to working as it did before the PendingIntent restarted the activity with the FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP flag.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the root of my problem was that I was finish()ing my root activity(leaving no activities on the stack) and thus closing the app when the user presses the back button.

By instead calling **moveTaskToBack(true)** when they press back on a root activity, I was getting the consistent "resume" functionality I wanted when the app was "re-launched" by the user.  And since I then wasn't fully closing and having to reopen/recreate the app, I was able to bypass the problem with the Intent being re-used for the Launcher activity.

Comment: can you post me an example of this please, im having similar issues.

Comment: yea, I am not sure what you mean. how did you achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you try to use finish(); and then call the Activity again?

Comment: Yes, I have.  I have tried restarting the activity from it's own onNewIntent() method to attempt to attach a new intent(one without the CLEAR_TOP flag) to the activity.  So I finish(), startActivity().  onCreate gets called again(so I can tell it actually "recreating" the activity, and it's flags = 0).  However, when I move the app to the background, then restart using a launcher the FIRST intent(the one from the PendingIntent) is the one being used as it once again clears top and has the same extras that were passed from the notification PendingIntent.

Comment: If you want to reload it again why don't you close the app instead of just moving it into background. Or just use finish(); in every activity to make sure that when you run your app again it will load the first Activity.

Comment: I don't want to just "reload it", I want to clear the Activity stack which is why I use the CLEAR_TOP flag.  I just want the app to RESUME properly after that when re-launching from the Recent Apps launcher list, rather than continuing to use the intent that has the CLEAR_TOP flag in it.